# How do I programatically empty trash?

Tags: buttons, trash

I need to create an "Empty Trash" button inside my plugin. How would I do it using PHP code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`wp_delete_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post).

To get all posts with the "trash" status:

`$trash = get_posts('post_status=trash&numberposts=-1');`

Then:

```
foreach($trash as $post)
  wp_delete_post($post->ID, $bypass_trash = true);
```

Comment: Cheers! It works!

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me.  I had to do the following:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => -1,
'post_status'      => 'trash'
    );

$trash = get_posts($args);

foreach($trash as $post)
{
    wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);      
}
```